# How to update message status with the Slack WEB API

Tags: node.js, twilio, slack-api

Is there a way to update the status of a message sent from the Slack Web API?

I'm using Slack to build a bot that send Slack messages as SMS using Twilio and I would like to notice the user that the message hasn't been sent if the Twilio call response is an error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a blog post by one of my colleagues that walks you through [building an SMS Slack bot in Python](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/build-sms-slack-bot-python.html). You can use it as a guide to translate the setup to [Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node).

The tutorial there shows you how to both send SMS messages [to Slack](https://api.slack.com/web) and receive Slack messages via SMS.

Specifically, the following route for receiving Slack messages as SMS:

```
@app.route('/slack', methods=['POST'])
def slack_post():
    if request.form['token'] == SLACK_WEBHOOK_SECRET:
        channel = request.form['channel_name']
        username = request.form['user_name']
        text = request.form['text']
        response_message = username   " in "   channel   " says: "   text
        twilio_client.messages.create(to=USER_NUMBER, from_=TWILIO_NUMBER,
                                      body=response_message)
    return Response(), 200
```

In addition to the code above you could handle any Twilio errors received on a [message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#sms-status-values) `Status` `ErrorCode` `ErrorMessage` and notify a user in Slack via the [`chat.update` method](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update).

Comment: Yes, I already found the `chat.update` method. But I was wondering if I could have the same feature as when a Slack message hasn't been sent due to network error.

Comment: I don't think you would have availability to override the Slack network error with an error coming from Twilio. Seems like you have to keep track via webhooks and create custom reporting: https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks